# Asymetric Perspectiv View

Tags: camera, webgl, perspective, frustum, view

I am building a addon component that will show synthesized 3D view of the world (kind of FLIR camera simulation). The problem I am facing is that currently I am using Symmetric Perspective View with an eye pointed always on the center of the screen. I can manipulate field of view in both vertical and horizontal dimension however what I cannot do is to move the eye point view from the center, so that I can see 15 degrees up and 30 down while my eyes are pointing at at the screen at point that is located at 1/3 from the top of the viewport. Below is the picture of what I want to achieve, assuming the eye point is on sea level looking straight ahead to the horizon.

[image: View]

I tried several techniques, I tried to enlarge my viewport proportionally and then increase FOVY and clip the viewport to have again 45 degree view, then I tried to manipulate the camera to look 15 degrees down, but none of the results are satisfactory, because the horizon of my 3d world view was never in range of 15 degrees up and 30 down and this is my requirement

I guess the correct way is to define the correct frustum. Please confirm this is the case and how to set it assuming that:
FOV=64
FOVY=45
ratio 1:5
near plane = 1
far = 500000000.0

Comment: It may be useful to tag your question with the graphics api/library you're using. If I recall correctly, projection matrices for DirectX and OpenGL (and the methods for creating/manipulating them) are not necessarily equivalent, so an answer would need to know which convention to target.

Comment: I am using WebGL